# volatile argument in sc_memset

Tags: c, typedef, volatile, memset

A part of the C program that I am writing includes initialization of an input table using sc_memset() function. The table is defined by a typedef struct as shown below.

```
typedef struct {
    UINT32 switchnum;
    UINT32 feedback[8];
    UINT32 switch_output[8];
} SWITCH_CHECK_IN;

SWITCH_CHECK_IN switch_input_table;
```

All the table elements, that is switchnum, feedback and switch_output should be initialized to zero.The sc_memset function prototype to be used for initialization is :

```
extern void sc_memset (volatile unsigned char *dest, unsigned long n, unsigned char data);
```

I have written the initialization code and because of the type differences in SWITCH_CHECK_IN & volatile unsigned char, I have tried to do some casting as below (I have tried several cast statements) but everytime I get a 'passing arg 1 of sc_memeset from incompatible pointer type' error.

```
while( *(volatile unsigned char *) &switch_input_table) {
{
   sc_memset( &switch_input_table, sizeof(switch_input_table), 0 );
}
```

I'm new to C so I am not quite sure if my general approach is correct. Kindly,
1. Where am I going wrong? Could you please show me the correct way. 
2. What other methods can be used? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The cast you do in the while loop has no influence on the arguments you pass to sc_memset.

Comment: `sc_memset` expects a pointer to unsigned char but you pass a pointer to a struct. Try: `sc_memset( (unsigned char *)&switch_input_table, ..`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, Got it! I've corrected it and it's not showing any errors. Thank you.

Comment: @Mat, Is that so? I thought by casting the variables take on the new type henceforth. Or have I done it wrong?

Comment: Casting doesn't change a variable's type (nothing does). It does change the type of the expression. If you have an int name foo, `(float) foo` doesn't modify foo in any way, but that expression is of type float and its value is the result of an int to float conversion of foo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the pointer to struct into a pointer to unsigned char, just like you do in the `while` condition:

`sc_memset( (unsigned char*)&switch_input_table`, ...

You shouldn't need `volatile` in the cast - the function implicitly adds `volatile` type qualifier to the passed parameter. Why it has `volatile`, I have no idea - it's fishy code unless the function expects a hardware register etc as input.

Comment: thank you for your input. I've corrected it and the errors are gone. Also, could you suggest references for further reading on 'volatile' and 'casting'? I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: @Hummingirl [This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/409570/6102) was written regarding the use of `volatile` in embedded systems, but it's pretty universal to any hardware-related programming. Regarding "casting" there's not much to understand here - consider a function `void f (const int* ptr)`. You can pass a `int*` to this function and the function guarantees that the pointed-at data will not be modified. `volatile` follows the very same rules as `const`, but it often doesn't make sense to have a function guarantee that it will treat the data as `volatile`.

Comment: thank you so much. I will definitely read it sometime, and on the other topics as well. Cheers!